# How do you prevent resizing of a shape/textbox but allow moving?

Tags: excel, vba

I have shapes that serve as markers in the sense that I will later read coordinates off of these markers. I want to prevent these shapes from being resized, but allow them to be dragged and dropped around the page. They are currently rectangles, but can be substituted with textboxes if needed.

Unfortunately locking the objects and protecting the page just prevents me from interacting with them at all.

Comment: Are you using active controls or the controls on the userform?

Comment: @LunaloJohn I'm using activex controls directly on the spreadsheet